# How can I get Value from a Bootstrap4 Dropdownlist? and input text?

Tags: php, html, forms, bootstrap-4

I want to take the input from user by PHP where I have a drop-down list and a Text input, I want to store the values of these in two different variables I am new to PHP and currently learning it, Is there any way we could take the values from dropdown list via Php method? I don't want to store this in a database, Just want to get the values from text and dropdown input and want to store it in 2 different variables.
My Code:

```
<div class="input-group">
               <input type="text" placeholder="Type Your Query Here: Ex:- Game Of Thrones etc...." class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button"
                    name="searchQuery">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Select File Type</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" name="queryType" >
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" value="(mkv|mp4|avi|mov|mpg|wmv)">Movies/Series</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" value=".exe">Games</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" value=".exe">Softwares</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" value="#">Games</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" value=".mp4|mp3">Music</a>
                        <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Other Databases Search</a>


                        <?php
                        if(isset($_POST['queryType'])) {
                              echo "selected size: ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['queryType']);
                              }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: clear your question you want store in database / show in another file ?

Comment: You'd need a `<form>` element with method POST if you want to use `$_POST` and [form elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Basic_native_form_controls) to get their value. You won't get values from your dropdown, those are simple links

Answer (score 2):

something like this

```
<?php
// your database connection
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
echo $_POST["name"]."<br>";
echo $_POST["gender"]."<br>";
}
else{
?>
<form action="" method ="post">
<input type = "text" name = "name" required>
<br><br>
<select name=gender>
<option value= "Female"> Female </option>
<option value= "Male"> Male </option>
</select><br><br>

<input type="submit" value=submit name=submit>
</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, But How can I modify my present code to make it work?